# JSONRPC server returns empty result

Tags: json, go, rpc

I've coded a simple JSONRPC server to test Go's capabilities, but I'm stuck, always getting an empty result, without error and correct id. I've got the following Go code:
    package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/rpc"
    "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
)

type Experiment int

func (e *Experiment) Test(i *string, reply *string) error {
    s := "Hello, " + *i
    reply = &s
    log.Println(s, reply)
    return nil
}

func main() {
    exp := new(Experiment)
    server := rpc.NewServer()
    server.Register(exp)
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":1234")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("listen error:", err)
    }
    for {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        server.ServeCodec(jsonrpc.NewServerCodec(conn))
    }
}
```

No matter what I tried, I've always got the following response:

```
{"id":1,"result":"","error":null}
```

Logging shows everything is working as it should in the server.

```
2013/07/17 15:17:13 Hello, Paulo 0xc200090ac0
```

Any ideas on what's going on? I'm using the latest stable version of Go, v1.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your reply is of type pointer to string. That is okay and even required as the second argument is used to return the answer. But then you do:

```
s := "Hello, " + *i
reply = &s
```

Which translates to:

- Construct a new string with a new value.
- Let reply point to this new string

This lets the string which is returned completely unaffected.
Try

```
*reply = s
```

Comment: Hum, that's great! I should study pointers a little, as this is my first foray in a language with that. I cannot upvote yet, but will later. Thanks for taking time to explain!